# Trick a docker containers DNS to resolve a different url

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns

I am not sure I know the terminology to describe this correctly, my apologies.

But for a contrived example. Say I have a docker container that runs code that accesses "google.com". But I want all requests that the container sets to "google.com" to actually go to "facebook.com". In other words I want the DNS lookup of one domain name to use another domain when reloving. Is there a way to do this with docker or docker-compose?

My ask is a bit more than this, because I know that often multiple websites are hosted on the same server (same IP), so I need a way for the conversion to happen at the domain name level, not at the IP level.

Thank you

Comment: I'm bit confuse, you wanna that container continuous using "google.com" but resolv this name to another address?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a DNS lookup of one domain to resolve to another one, you have 2 options.

1. Modify the Container /etc/hosts file. By default any DNS lookup is done there. You schould do that in the Dockerfile.

[Modify /etc/hosts in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302867/how-to-update-etc-hosts-file-in-docker-image-during-docker-build)

2. Maintain your own DNS servers with all mapping records. On container runtime just pass the DNS server.

[Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

> --dns   The IP address of a DNS server.

Comment: Modifying the container's hosts file will likely fail because docker will clobber the /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
$ docker run --add-host foo:127.0.0.42 alpine ping foo -c 3
PING foo (127.0.0.42): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.42: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.42: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.42: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms

--- foo ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.045/0.058/0.070 ms
```

Look for --add-host parameter for [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) or [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#extra_hosts) for docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

The `extra_hosts` setting in `docker-compose` might help you. [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts)